# Cubic model coefficient drastically different that what it actually is but provided correct prediction

Tags: r, polynomial-math, coefficients

I tried to fit a cubic model and use it for prediction in R, while the predictions provided are accurate, the coefficient of the model doesn't make any sense given the predicted values.

Below is the output when I run `summary(lm(Blur ~ poly(logMAR, 3), data = df))`:

```
Call:
lm(formula = Blur ~ poly(logMAR, 3), data = df)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-20.7838  -2.0661  -0.0868   2.3009  23.8918 

Coefficients:
                 Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)       35.0000     0.7775  45.015   <2e-16 ***
poly(logMAR, 3)1 230.6529     6.7782  34.029   <2e-16 ***
poly(logMAR, 3)2  94.3878     6.7782  13.925   <2e-16 ***
poly(logMAR, 3)3  19.6777     6.7782   2.903   0.0049 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 6.778 on 72 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9497,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9476 
F-statistic: 453.4 on 3 and 72 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Subsequently, when calling `coef(model)`, it returned:

```
     (Intercept) poly(logMAR, 3)1 poly(logMAR, 3)2 poly(logMAR, 3)3 
        35.00000        230.65294         94.38777         19.67767
```

Which is accurate to the summary, but when I call for `predict(model, newdata = data.frame(logMAR = c(0.37, 0.74, 1.15))` it returned:

```
        1         2         3 
 3.492585 11.469869 31.099493
```

However, if I calculate the prediction manually according to the coefficients, the answers would be:

```
[1] 134.2600 265.3438 455.0060
```

After various comparisons with plots, the smaller output makes way more sense, and the coefficients from R's summary seem to be too large, making the manual calculation inaccurate. I sanity-checked the model using alternative software and online tools, which returned smaller coefficients of β0 = 1.3415, β1 = 0.9073, β2 = 9.2517 and β3 = 10.8354.

Manual calculation with the smaller coefficients aligns with the `predict()` function in R.

```
        1         2         3 
 3.492585 11.469869 31.099493
```

Is there a reason why the coefficients are that big in R's `summary()`, am I doing the manual calculation incorrectly or looking at the wrong place?

Comment: How are you calculating the predictions manually? `poly` uses orthogonal polynomials which are much more stable, not a naive `b0 + b1 * x + b2 * x^2 + b3 * x^3` approach... are you doing that as well? [You can read about the differences here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/258307).

Comment: Also, please save the Rstudio tag for problems specific to RStudio - like if you have code that doesn't work in RStudio but does work in a different R interface, like the command line or the RGui.

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments, `poly` uses orthogonal polynomials by default and **not** simply `a0 + a1 * x + a2 * x ^ 2 + a3 *  x ^ 3`. You can, however, ask for *raw* polynomials.

The following toy example illustrates the issue:

```r
set.seed(123)
d <- data.frame(x = runif(100))
d$y <- (d$x + 4) ^ 3 + rnorm(100, sd = .2)

mo <- lm(y ~ poly(x, degree = 3), data = d)
mr <- lm(y ~ poly(x, degree = 3, raw = TRUE), data = d)

bd <- data.frame(x = 2)
predict(mo, bd)
#        1 
# 220.7312
predict(mr, bd) ## same
#        1 
# 220.7312

sum(coef(mr) * 2 ^ (0:3)) ## raw polys can be interpreted like this
# [1] 220.7312
sum(coef(mo) * 2 ^ (0:3)) ## however, orthogonal ones not --> wrong
# [1] 480.2738
sum(coef(mo) * c(1, predict(poly(d$x, degree = 3), 2))) ## but you can use them this way
# [1] 220.7312
```